# React/Javascript Having trouble implementing dictionary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I'm trying to implement a dictionary in my React project. I'm guessing it's basic javascript so if you're not familiar with React you might still be able to help.

My goal is to have a *dict* which contains questions, where each question has an array of answers. I want to be able to add a question first, and then add answers later.

I can add the record but then I'm having trouble modifying the answer array:

**Initial**

```
const [dict, setDict] = React.useState([])
```

**Adding dictionary record**

```
question = "question1"
const newDict = dict.concat({ key: question1, value: [] });
setDict(newDict);
```

**Modifying dictionary value**

```
const answer = "valueToAdd"
const newDict = dict;
newDict["test"].concat(answer);
setDict(newDict);
```

I'm getting the following error. Seems like newDict["test"] is undefined, even though I just added it. What am I doing wrong?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
```

Also, is this the correct way to append to a dictionary? I'm doing it like this so dictionary will re-render.

Comment: what is answer here ?

Comment: `const newDict = dict.concat({ key: "test", value: [] });` is an Array not Object.
`newDict => [{ key: "test", value: [] }]`

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi answer is a string

Comment: answer should be added to the value array ? if I understand you correctly

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Indeed

Comment: since newDict is an array having one element , you can do this ```var answer = "valueToAdd" ; newDict[0].value.push(answer)```

Comment: @korzhyk I'm not sure what you mean, can you please create an answer and explain what you're doing?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi It's 1 element for convenience in this post :) It's going to have multiple key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are setting the initial value of your dict state variable to an empty array rather than a true dictionary like you may be intending. Javascript objects behave very similarly to dictionaries in other languages, so you may want to use an object for this instead.

**Declaring your state**

```js
const [dict,setDict] = useState({})
```

Here we are initializing the state (dict) to an empty javascript object. These objects behave similarly to the dictionaries you are familiar with in other languages.

**Adding a key value pair**

```js
setDict(prevDict => ({...prevDict, newKey: []}))
```

Here we are using an arrow function to provide the previous state to the object we will be using to update the state. This is done to keep the previous state immutable. The spread/rest operator "..." is being used to collect all of the values of the previous state, then add the new key-value pair

**Updating Values**

```js
setDict(prevDict => ({...prevDict, keyToUpdate: [...prevDict.keyToChange, "newValue"]}))
```

Similar to the above, the spread/rest operator is being used, this time in two places. First to retain the keys of the previous state, second to keep all of the values from the array that we are going to be adding to.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! I think you're right, I didn't mean for it to be an array. I tried your solution though and I'm getting syntax errors! https://gyazo.com/0cae14011974f0415f40140541c83d51.png

Comment: Happy to help! My b, I was missing parentheses, wrote the whole thing here, and didn't catch it! Next time I will be sure to try it out on my end first.

Comment: Thank you so much, your post has been in a great help and my issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your dict can be an object literal.

```js
//function that creates a unique key every time
const key = ((key) => () => key++)(1);
//item is pure component, won't re render unless props change
const Item = React.memo(function Item({ addValue, item }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(item, undefined, 2)}</pre>
      <button
        onClick={() => addValue(item.key, Date.now())}
      >
        add random value
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  //dict local state
  const [dict, setDict] = React.useState({});
  //add item to dict using useCallback so function
  //  addDict is only created whe App mounts
  const addDict = React.useCallback(
    () =>
      //callback to setDict prevent dict to be a dependency
      //  of useCallback
      setDict((dict) => {
        const k = key();
        return {
          ...dict,//copy dict
          [k]: { key: k, values: [] },//set k with new object
        };
      }),
    []//no dependency
  );
  //function to add value to dict use useCallback again
  //  so function is only created when App mounts
  const addValue = React.useCallback(
    (key, value) =>
      //pass callback to setDict to prevent dependency
      setDict((dict) => ({
        ...dict,//copy dict
        [key]: {//set this key
          ...dict[key],//copy dict[key]
          values: dict[key].values.concat(value),//add value
        },
      })),
    []
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={addDict}>add dict</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {Object.values(dict).map((dict) => (
            <Item
              key={dict.key}
              addValue={addValue}
              item={dict}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

More info on updating immutable state can be found [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)

Comment: Hmm this seems rather inefficient, do you think there's a better way to handle my problem? I guess I was confused with the "Map" object in Java for example, where you can just find the value by key.. that's essentially what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @SJ19 Updated answer